# Events not added when hosted on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

Creating an event using the [create event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API call in Microsoft Graph with the [.NET SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet). This is my code:

```cs
private async Task addEvent(Event @event)
{
    using(var task = Task.Run(async() => await client
        .Me
        .Calendars[calendarID]
        .Events.Request()
        .AddAsync(@event)))
    {
        while (!task.IsCompleted)
            Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
}
```

This is running and working as expected on my local machine and on IIS in a VM by another provider - has been for about 6 months now.

However, when this runs on an Azure App Service, it doesn't throw an exception but no events are actually created. Read-only calls to get events and calendars work, but this one just doesn't. Any ideas appreciated - maybe there's a setting in an app service?

Comment: Why not make the function contents just `await client.Me.Calendars[calendarID].Events.Request().AddAsync(@event);`?

Comment: Had this previously, but ran into an issue where the server hanged on this indefinitely in production and the above resolved

Comment: what is the content of `@event`?

Comment: If it's a .NET Framework project (not Core), you may need to use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` with functions that returns Tasks to prevent deadlocks.